# How to pass static values in SwiftUI from one View to another?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm new to learning SwiftUI and XCode and am unable to figure out how to pass a variable from view to another.  I read on @State and @Binding variables but from what I can tell that is for values that change.  I have a static value that I calculate based on the date when the user opens the app.

The variable is the current moon phase and is stored locally in my main ContentView.  I want to pass this variable to a second view that's accessed by clicking a NavigationLink.

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        let currentMoonPhaseArray = calculateMoonPhase()
        let moonPhase = currentMoonPhaseArray[0]
        
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators:true) {
                VStack(spacing:3){
                    NavigationLink(destination: MoonPhaseView()){
                        Text("Moon Phase - " + moonPhase)
                    }
                }
            }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .navigationTitle("MySky")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        
    }
}
```

**MoonPhaseView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct MoonPhaseView: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("MoonPhaseView!")
        }
    }
}

struct MoonPhaseView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MoonPhaseView()
    }
}
```

My goal is to have the calculated moon phase from ContentView.swift be passed to the MoonPhaseView.swift.  I believe that bindings are the correct approach from what I've read, but all binding implementations seem to be for updating views often.

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown what the type of `moonPhase` is, so I'm just going to use `String` as an example.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    func calculateMoonPhase() -> [String] {
        return ["Full","Waxing","Waning"]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let currentMoonPhaseArray = calculateMoonPhase()
        let moonPhase = currentMoonPhaseArray[0]
        
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators:true) {
                VStack(spacing:3){
                    NavigationLink(destination: MoonPhaseView(phase: moonPhase)){
                        Text("Moon Phase - " + moonPhase)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .navigationTitle("MySky")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

struct MoonPhaseView: View {
    var phase : String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("MoonPhaseView!")
            Text(phase)
        }
    }
}

struct MoonPhaseView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MoonPhaseView(phase: "Full")
    }
}
```

Note that every time `MoonPhaseView` is used, you must provide a `phase` parameter so that it has a value to fill `var phase : String`. You could provide a default value, but that doesn't seem like it would do much good here.

---

Not directly related to your question, but I might suggest that calculating the phase in the `body` *might* lead to undesirable results, especially if it's an expensive calculation or it has to contact an API or something. You might want to consider doing this in `onAppear` and keeping it in a `@State` variable in your `ContentView`, or perhaps even using an `ObservableObject` as a view model and storing the phase there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Environment" to pass system-wide settings to views and child views.

For example:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    let moonPhaseValue = "Waxing"   // <--- some value 
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environment(\.moonPhase, moonPhaseValue) // <--- pass it around
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.moonPhase) var moonPhase   // <--- the value again
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: MoonPhaseView()) {
                    Text("Moon Phase - " + moonPhase)
                }
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct MoonPhaseView: View {
    @Environment(\.moonPhase) var moonPhase  // <--- the value again
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("MoonPhaseView is \(moonPhase)")
        }
    }
}

// create your own EnvironmentKey
struct MoonPhaseKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: String = "Full"
}
// create your own EnvironmentValues
extension EnvironmentValues {
    var moonPhase: String {
        get { return self[MoonPhaseKey] }
        set { self[MoonPhaseKey] = newValue }
    }
}
```